# get common lines in two files with different number of cols

Tags: file, compare, match

I have two txt files like this

```
file1.txt
>100kb
ENSG00000004534
ENSG00000006453
ENSG00000011105
ENSG00000011275
ENSG00000014164
ENSG00000018408
ENSG00000028277
ENSG00000029534
ENSG00000039139
ENSG00000039560

    file2.txt
    Chromosome  Start   End      Strand   Gene     Name        n. Totaln   X          Y            Z
    chr6    143495847   143497388   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 6   6   0.019896973 0.047572512 0.021542861
    chr6    143497497   143501931   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 5   6   0.223448446 0.048568393 0.13196303
    chr6    143502122   143502354   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 4   6   0.016900261 0.020203774 0
    chr6    143502565   143503912   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 3   6   0.019807321 0.04735816  0.042891587
    chr6    143504252   143507236   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 2   6   0.646528636 0.289839866 0.568757988
    chr6    143507424   143511410   -   fuca2   ENSG00000001036 1   6   0.730370424 0.363806977 0.285561993
    chr1    24415904    24419290    +   nipal3  ENSG00000001461 1   10  2.226799058 1.355237649 1.731537131
    chr1    24419640    24440171    +   nipal3  ENSG00000001461 2   10  12.37756228 10.31381565 11.11609581
    chr1    24440240    24442054    +   nipal3  ENSG00000001461 3   10  0.339855898 0.334590043 0.216452329
    chr1    24442226    24445184    +   nipal3  ENSG00000001461 4   10  0.34341861  0.169048777 0.349954241
```

I would like to get a new file that shows all the cols in file2.txt for each coincidence in file1.txt

So far I've tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$6 in a{print}' file1.txt file2.txt >proof
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?